# Press ctrl + tab in selenium webdrievr

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> in selenium webdriver? Google Answers are too old and the official documentation lacks the info.

I tried everything. It can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> for example, but it's impossible to guess how to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to so something like this. You did not say what code you are using and the below is C#.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
```

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='myname']")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Tab);

Comment: there's no such thing as Keys. there's only Key method or whatever. But I think I know how to do it
I need an extension "switch to previous tab and make a shortcut in it for example to ctrl+q so it should work... I'll write a bit later if it worked

Comment: No such thing as keys? What I posted there is working code lol. Make sure you have the library using OpenQA.Selenium; added.

Comment: mmm I use Javascript and selenium webdriver module....I dont's see Keys there. sendkeys ok. but only Key not Keys... what's OpenQA? thank you:) I've installed selenium via npm

Comment: no it doesn't work...beacuse the driver is not pressing keys it's just emulate it within the browser... so I need another npm to rpess keys...I found one but it's not working prorperly....